# SQL query using WHERE clause misses swedish "Ö" sign

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, sql-server-express, adodb

I'm using VBScript (vbs) to execute an SQL query on Microsoft SQL Server Express 2014. When I use a WHERE clause with IN terms with swedish characters are not found, in this case "Ö".

Testing COLLATE in the query without any result.

```
"SELECT * FROM OrderDetail od "& _
"LEFT JOIN Article a ON a.id=od.ArticleId  "& _
"WHERE od.Orderid='6881' AND a.Name IN ('ÖF', 'LIV')"

    Set ConDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
ConDB.Open "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Server="&strDbServer&";Database="&strDbName&";Uid="&strDbUser&";Pwd="&strDbPassword&";stmt=SET NAMES 'utf-8';"
Set ConnectDB = ConDB
```

Comment: Is the script saved in ANSI or Unicode format?

Comment: What happens if you run the script from SSMS first?

Comment: Try it with `a.Name IN (N'ÖF', N'LIV')`.  The `N` indicates you want to use unicode.

Comment: The script file is saved in UTF8, in SMSS it works fine but not executed from vb file. Will add the database connection code. Tried the N so: IN (N'ÖF', 'LIV') but didnt work

Comment: You also have a logical error here. You have a left join to Article but then logically turn that into an inner join in your where clause by returning only certain rows from that table. I would make it an inner join and move the a.Name predicate to the inner join.

Comment: Im not sure i fully understand how i should change it to INNER, just change LEFT to INNER? The OrderDetail table has all articles characteristics for one order, Article table just has the general article information. In this case it is two of the items i need to show. But i still dont understand how i can get the correct result in SSMS and not when querying from Vbs? Thanks

Comment: Check the [database collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-2014). Also, are the table columns defined as unicode types `nvarchar` etc.?

Comment: I changed the a.name field nvarchar(150) instead of varchar(150). Still dont get it. Collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, Should that be able to handle Ö, and since it works in SSMS?